# Table join with sub-query not working in hibernate java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to get the latest transaction per user.
So I am trying to use self join with the latest timestamp.

When I am executing the same query in postgresql, it's working fine, but when trying in java (hibernate) it's giving below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 76 [SELECT  a FROM BillingTransactionHistory a,(SELECT max(timeStamp) btimeStamp, appUserId bappUserId FROM BillingTransactionHistory b group by appUserId )  WHERE a.appUserId = bappUserId AND a.timeStamp=btimeStamp AND a.appUserId IN :hrIds AND a.balance>=1 ]

My query is

```
SELECT  a FROM BillingTransactionHistory a,(SELECT max(timeStamp) timeStamp, appUserId FROM BillingTransactionHistory b group by appUserId )  b WHERE a.appUserId = b.appUserId AND a.timeStamp=b.timeStamp
```

And the code snippet is

```
em.createQuery("SELECT  a FROM BillingTransactionHistory a,(SELECT max(timeStamp) timeStamp, appUserId FROM BillingTransactionHistory b group by appUserId )  b " + 
                " WHERE a.appUserId = b.appUserId AND a.timeStamp=b.timeStamp "
                + " AND a.balance>=1 ",
                BillingTransactionHistory.class).getResultList();
```

Can anyone help me, how can I get it resolved.

Comment: I think you cannot use just the table alias in `SELECT a FROM BillingTransactionHistory a ...`, you must either select everything by `SELECT * FROM ...` or specify the columns you want to receive by `SELECT a.ID, a.something, a.somethingElse FROM ...`.

Comment: We can use it. If using 'SELECT a FROM BillingTransactionHistory a, BillingTransactionHistory b' then also it will work, The issue is with the only subquery.

Comment: OK, then maybe the double `b` is an issue. What exactly are you trying to achieve by this query? What data (in words) are you expecting to get?

Comment: no, double is not an issue.  Also, I need the latest transactions (based on timeStamp) per user. Technically, in java hibernate it will be a list of entities.

Comment: Can't you just do `SELECT DISTINCT max(timeStamp) timeStamp, appUserId FROM BillingTransactionHistory WHERE balance >= 1` then?

Comment: Appreciate your help but It will not serve my purpose. Based on timestamp I will not be able to get the latest full entity for each user.

Comment: In postgres, you should be able to do `SELECT DISTINCT ON(appUserId) timeStamp, appUserId FROM BillingTransactionHistory WHERE balance >= 1 ORDER BY appUserId, timeStamp DESC;` to get the latest transaction per user.  I'm not sure how this translates to hibernate, though.